# parser:foundCharacters - why do I need "parser" here?

Tags: objective-c, parsing

```
(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{   
    currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: 

    [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];    
}
```

I'm trying to figure out why i need the parser here. All the trimming is done on the string so why am I sending the parser too? I don't see anything related to the parser inside the method. Is that just for reporting ? (there's a good chance that i don't understand what's it the parser.)

Comment: What about your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12956011/1037210)? It appears to be the same as this one?

Comment: In my previous question i didn't understand the syntax or what the method does but now I'm past that. I just don't understand the parser part of it.

Comment: Have you [read this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000186i)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a delegate method. The `parser` parameter is there because you *may* need it if you use the same delegate for multiple parsers.